# RecyclerView OnCheckedChangeListener bug when click TabLayout

Tags: android, kotlin

so I have `TabLayout` with `RecyclerView`, when I click the tab it reloads the `RecyclerView` with new sets of data, but I'm having a problem with `onCheckedChangeListener`.

When I change the tab it reloads the new set of data but it also triggers the `onCheckedChangeListener` too.

here's the code that I have

**ADAPTER**

```
class ProductAdapter(
    private val product: ArrayList<ProductDataRs>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.DataViewHolder>() {

    var onItemClick: ((ProductDataRs) -> Unit)? = null

    inner class DataViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(productDataRs: ProductDataRs) {
            itemView.text_view_product_name.text = productDataRs.name.toString()
            itemView.text_view_description.text = productDataRs.description.toString()
            itemView.text_view_price.text = "Php ${productDataRs.price.toString()}"

            itemView.switch_product.isChecked = productDataRs.status != 0

            itemView.switch_product.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton: CompoundButton, b: Boolean ->
                onItemClick?.invoke(product[adapterPosition])
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        DataViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_product_layout, parent,
                false
            )
        )

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = product.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(product[position])
    }
```

**FRAGMENT**

```
private fun setupUI() {
        fragmentProductsBinding.recyclerViewProducts.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(activity?.applicationContext)
        productAdapter = ProductAdapter(arrayListOf())
        fragmentProductsBinding.recyclerViewProducts.adapter = productAdapter


        productAdapter.onItemClick = { product ->
            Log.e("asd", "asd")
//            updateProductStatus(product.id!!, if (product.status == 0) 1 else 0)
        }

        fragmentProductsBinding.tabLayoutProducts.addOnTabSelectedListener(object :
            TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

                var iterator = (data)?.iterator()
                if (iterator != null) {
                    for ((index, rs) in iterator.withIndex()) {
                        if (index == tab.position) {
                            rs.products?.let { retrieveList(it) }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ProductsFragment", "no data")
                }
            }

        })
    }
```

Comment: I could not find `onClickListener` in your code!

Comment: in `adapter` I have 
itemView.switch_product.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton: CompoundButton, b: Boolean ->
                onItemClick?.invoke(product[adapterPosition])
            }

and in `fragment` I have 

productAdapter.onItemClick

Comment: sorry what I meant is setOnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: Do you want to trigger it when it is on or off?

Answer (score 1):

**`If`** you want to trigger it when it is **on(isChecked)** you should change your code to :

```
   itemView.switch_product.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton: CompoundButton, b: Boolean ->
        if(b) onItemClick?.invoke(product[adapterPosition])
        
    }
```

**`If`** **`else`** you want to trigger it when it is **off(unChecked)** you should change your code to :

```
   itemView.switch_product.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton: CompoundButton, b: Boolean ->
        if(!b) onItemClick?.invoke(product[adapterPosition])
        
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer by the way, this fix my issue I add `itemView.switch_product.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)` so when I change the tab and refresh the recycler view it would not trigger the event listener

Comment: Where did you added that line?

Answer (score 0):

you can combine the TabLayout and viewPager2 and handle the recycler view in that fragment :

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2

i did the similar thing on this project i leave it down below if you want more examples:

https://github.com/ErfanDP/Erfan_Delavari_HW12_Maktab36
at first enter random name that doesn't matter